# If $(b,n)=1$, $n\mid(ad-bc)$ and $n\mid(a-b)$ then $n\mid (c-d)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Pretty straightforward. I am stuck on a problem, and would love it if someone could give me a small hint or nudge in the right direction.

The problem is $(b,n)=1$ and $n\mid(ad-bc)$ and $n\mid(a-b)$ implies that $n\mid(c-d)$.

What I have so far is that because $b$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $n\nmid b$, and since $n\mid (a-b)$, $n\nmid a$, because if not $b$ would be divisble by $n$. However, this is where I get stuck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Quang Hoang's hint is quite good, I would also suggest an application of what is known as 'Euclid's Lemma', namely if $a|bc$ and $gcd(a,b) = 1$ then $a|c$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:    $ad-bc=(a-b)d-(c-d)b$.

Answer (score 2):

Using rules of moduar-arithmetic we have:
$$ad-bc\equiv 0\pmod n$$ but $a\equiv b\pmod n$
therefore replacing $$bd-bc\equiv 0\pmod n$$ from here because $(b,n)=1$,
$c\equiv d\pmod n$